# Special characters (with tilde) in NSIS MessageBox

Tags: localization, special-characters, nsis

I'm having some trouble with the following message box and a spanish character:

```
MessageBox MB_OK "Se ha producido un error durante la instalación del Framework .NET."
```

That is actually showing:

```
Se ha producido un error durante la instalaci?n del Framework .NET.
```

Without the 'ó' character.

I think the language is correctly loaded, with the following lines in the start of the file:

```
;Loads the Nsis language file, necessary for unistall messages.
LoadLanguageFile "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Language files\Spanish.nlf"
```

I have seen some solutions, but they used very different code and I bet there is a very simple way to do this. Thanks a lot!

PD: I'm using NSIS 2.46. I know I should upgrade to 2.50, but it's not doable right now.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of NSIS do you use? Are you sure the Spanish language file (.nlf for classic GUI and .nsh for MUI2) are correct?

If they are OK then try to build your installer with UNICODE version of NSIS - download from http://www.scratchpaper.com/

It fully supports UNICODE - with all special characters (like in Slovak language (ľščťžýáíéäňú) or also Chinese, Japanese, ...

Comment: Thanks, I know I should use that version but in my company they didn't want me to mess with that right now. I'll try to update that eventually. I'll try to check the language file.